# What is the meaning of this Feynman's statement?

Tags: soft-question, everyday-life, atomic-physics, complex-systems

Richard Feynman has a strange statement in first lecture of his known book "Feynman Lectures on Physics. He says

> If a piece of steel or a piece of salt, consisting of atoms one next to the other, can have such interesting properties; if water—which is nothing but these little blobs, mile upon mile of the same thing over the earth—can form waves and foam, and make rushing noises and strange patterns as it runs over cement; if all of this, all the life of a stream of water, can be nothing but a pile of atoms, how much more is possible? If instead of arranging the atoms in some definite pattern, again and again repeated, on and on, or even forming little lumps of complexity like the odor of violets, we make an arrangement which is always different from place to place, with different kinds of atoms arranged in many ways, continually changing, not repeating, how much more marvelously is it possible that this thing might behave? Is it possible that that “thing” walking back and forth in front of you, talking to you, is a great glob of these atoms in a very complex arrangement, such that the sheer complexity of it staggers the imagination as to what it can do? When we say we are a pile of atoms, we do not mean we are merely a pile of atoms, because a pile of atoms which is not repeated from one to the other might well have the possibilities which you see before you in the mirror.

I think he wants to emphasize on repeating the arrangement of atoms, but suddenly, in the last sentence, he talks about mirror and state his sentence strangely (at least for me!). Does anybody know what he wants to say in the last sentence?

Comment: Frankly this might be equally or even more at home on [ell.se], [english.se] or [philosophy.se]. It's not really about physics but about the poetic use of language and if the whole is or is not more than the sum of its parts.

Comment: This seems not to be a physics question, but a comprehension issue.

Comment: He is saying that being a pile of atoms is a rather marvelous thing, not something to be thought of as merely .... a pile of atoms can be a very impressive thing, like you, me and whatever else you find inthis world.  And it's a wonderful world.

Answer (score 4):

He's saying "look in the mirror" - what you see is yourself, and you are more than a simple pile of atoms.  He is introducing some ideas from complexity theory by means of repetition of scenarios, and self-reflection, pun  intended (by Feynman).